# How can I set certain frame per second?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started learning Unity, and I realized that there are two parts in C# script(start and update). I understand the start part since it runs only 1 time but Update quite doesn't make sense. The frame that I get depends on the performance of my computer(and the performance also changes unexpectedly), then how do I make a character move at the same speed every moment? For example, if I were to make a character move 1 in z-direction per second, how would I do it?

Comment: Your question should not be how to modify the frame-rate but rather "ow to move with a frame-rate independent speed" => https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should modify the framerate of your game to modify the speed of your character but instead you should use the float `Time.deltaTime` which correspond to the time passed since last frame :

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

I would recommend you to follow the [unityLearn Essential Pathway](https://learn.unity.com/pathway/unity-essentials) which is a very good starting point for Unity.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to fix framerates, especially in the mobile area. You can just do `Application.targetFrameRate` [Unity docs on it](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html)

other things to bare in mind are vsync. so not as helpful as people think. Essentially this can halve the frame rate you set.

then as per Pierre's answer you would use Time.deltaTime to even out the speed should the frame rate vary a little.